# trying to add user to sudoers group gives me error

Tags: adduser

im adding one user to the sudoers file and when i enter the command `sudo adduser <username> sudo`, shows error `<username>` is not on the sudoers file. this incident will be reported.

Any suggestion what could it be? why that error if im trying to add.

Comment: @PerlDuck, sorry, I didn't notice it. Then I'll delete my comment. Thank you for notifying me. I already posted an answer, I hope it helps solving the problems

Comment: @singrium No worries. Sometimes when I see weird commands obviously missing something I just hit "edit" to check the original text for such `<`…`>` parts.

Comment: That's a great idea to check the original text. I'll be doing the same too.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `sudo` , however you do not have the right to do so as you yourself are not a member of the sudo group. In such circumstances you will always get that error message when you attempt to use `sudo` for whatever reason. Example (notice that richard is not a member of sudo):

```
richard@s15:~$ groups
richard adm cdrom dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
richard@s15:~$ sudo ls -l
[sudo] password for richard:
richard is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Now, that same thing for me (notice that I am a member of the sudo group):

```
doug@s15:~$ groups
doug adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
doug@s15:~$ sudo ls -l
total 4112
drwxrwxr-x  2 doug doug   4096 Oct 25 16:37 audio
drwxr-xr-x 39 doug doug   4096 Oct 14  2016 backup_carrie_01
...
```

Furthermore, since I have the rights to do so, I can add richard to the sudo group:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo adduser richard sudo
Adding user `richard' to group `sudo' ...
Adding user richard to group sudo
Done.
```

And for a subsequent login for richard:

```
richard@s15:~$ groups
richard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
richard@s15:~$
```

Comment: True. But this suggests that the OP tried to add _himself_ to the `sudo` group (without being member of it), doesn't it? We dont't know whether the two "instances" of `<username>` in his post refer to the same or different unames.

Comment: Yes. The adduser part is a red herring, in my opinion. That error message only appears when a non `sudo` user tries to use `sudo`, at least that I am aware of. That is why in my answer I used a trivial command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the user to the sudoers file manually:

- Go to home directory by running command `cd`
- Then type `sudo su`

It will ask you to type your password to be in root user.

- Run `visudo`
- Then add this line to the end of the file (change `username` with your username:

  ```
  username        ALL=(ALL)      ALL
  ```
- Save and exit

**Credits:**
[Username is not in the sudoers file.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258865)